# Convertir lista de string a decimal

Tags: c#, lista

Tengo una lista con precios donde los guardo como `string` pero quiero cambiarlas a `decimal` y que tengan un formato como de moneda, que no se muestren todos los dígitos del precio.

Así es como tengo la lista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde la tengo almacenada en una lista sencilla.

```
List<string> listaPrecio = new List<string>();
```

Comment: Luisito, llevas tiempo en el sitio, https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 lectura recomendada, punto 3 especialmente. Saludos.

Comment: Puedes iterar (o recorrer) la lista y crear una nueva con la conversión que deseas puedes usar un foreach o bien googlea un poco acerca de linq select, básicamente recorrerá cada elemento y regresará una nueva lista con la transformación que le hagas al elemento https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/introduccion-rapida-a-linq-con-c-sharp.aspx

Comment: Esto es para hacer que??? si es para mostrar en pantalla, solo dale formato al string.. si es para hacer calculos, has la transformacion al hacer el calculo... no estaria entendiendo a que queres llegar...

Comment: Viendo que en tu lista existen cadenas no numéricas, te propongo `decimal.TryParse` dentro de un bucle, iterador o método de conversión de System.Linq. La clase `System.Math` te servirá para redondear o truncar los dígitos. Ej. `Math.Round(valor, 2)` si deseas 2 decimales después del punto.

Comment: @gbianchi Nada más quería darles un formato menos aparatoso.

Comment: @HéctorM. use el `decimal.tryParse` pero me devolvía un error al momento de pasarlos a la otra lista

Comment: Un formato menos aparatoso donde??? si es para mostrar, te vuelvo a repetir, que lo cambie la UI al mostrarlo... vos queres cambiarlo en el depurador??? ahi no tiene absolutamente nada de sentido cambiarlo....

Comment: Esa información no la muestro en ninguna interfaz, obtengo esa información de archivos que subo y la modifico.

Comment: Entonces salvo que sea para grabarlo, deberias modificarlo al grabarlo... la salida a un archivo es analoga a la salida en una pantalla... no tiene sentido tu paso intermedio...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solamente me cree otra lista de tipo `decimal` y le metí los datos de la lista que tengo, y los convertí a decimal y los redondee.

```
List<decimal> listaPrecioDecimal = listaPrecio
                .Skip(1)
                .Select(precio => Convert.ToDecimal(precio))
                .Select(precio => Decimal.Round(precio, 2))
                .ToList();
```